# Display entries including all locales for XML sitemap

Tags: localization

I’m trying to build an XML sitemap that contains all entries including those in a different locale. I thought the `localeEnabled(false)` would allow entries for all locales to be displayed, however, the following doesn’t seem to work:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').status('live').localeEnabled(false) %}
```

If is assign a locale:

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('pages').status('live').locale('de') %}
```

then the entry is displayed.

I have tried using `.locale(null)` and `.localeEnabled(null)` without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but I think the only way is to query for each locale and merge.

```
{% set siteLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocales %}
{% set pages = [] %}
{% for locale in siteLocales %}
    {% set localePages = craft.entries.section('pages').locale(locale.getId).find() %}
    {% set pages = pages|merge(localePages) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for page in pages %}
    {{ page.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Douglas. That definitely captures all the entries for all locales so I will use this method, but I am curious why the purpose of  `localeEnabled(false)`. [In the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#localeEnabled) it suggests would displays all entries irrespective of locale.

Comment: Having thought about this, I think this may be a bug. I’ll report it to P&T to see what they say.

Comment: I think localeEnabled(false), means display an entry that otherwise wouldn't show because it is not localeEnabled (in settings) for that locale. I don't think it has anything to do with showing other locales.

Comment: Ah. That kind of makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to help with this. I’ll run with your solution.